# meteor Java Script How to change background color in a cell

Tags: javascript, meteor

I googled alot about this Questions but sadly cant get it resolved.
What I want to accomplish is if a cell reached the status 2 it should get red.
It leads me to 
    document.getElementById('statusOfCell').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
which will work if I add it to my html site with the script tags but not within my meteor Application.

hello.html

```
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="background-color: aqua">Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> liste}}
</body>

<template name="liste">
  <table>
    {{#each listItem}}
        <tr class="{{listOfNumbers}}">
      <td id="statusOfCell">{{status}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</template>
```

hello.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
   Template.liste.helpers({
        listItem: [{status: 1}, {status: 1}, {status: 2}, {status: 1}],
    'listOfNumbers': function(){
        var listStatus = this.status;
         console.log(listStatus);
            if(listStatus == 2){
              statusOfCell=status;          
  document.getElementById('statusOfCell').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
     }
   })
  }
```

The console.log shows me the correct numbers. The Error Message is:
Cannot read property 'style' of null at Object
which occures because:
     document.getElementById() = null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Id` is duplicated by the loop, thus it cannot find the correct `Id` to set the color. There are several problems with your code though

- listOfNumbers: is a helper function, so it should return something for the class on the template
- Do not change the background when rendering the page through the loop. Instead, return the correct `css` class and then, specify the color for that `css` class

Comment: Thanks a lot, it took a while for me to understand.. just a newbee here :)